# No openerTabId property for popup windows

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I got two `html`s as follows.

#### index1.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <button 
        onclick="
            window.open(
                'https://www.google.com', 
                'sample')">
        click
     </button>
</body>
</html>
```

#### index2.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <button 
        onclick="
            window.open(
                'https://www.google.com', 
                'sample', 
                'height=200,width=150')">
        click
     </button>
</body>
</html>
```

button click on `index1` page opens Google page next to the current tab in the same window while `index2` opens it as a popup window.

I'm listening to `chrome.tabs.onCreated` events in the `background`.

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => console.log(tab.openerTabId));

// results
//index1 >>> 42
//index2 >>> undefined
```

Here I believe `openerTabId` should exist for popup windows as well. `chrome.tabs.get()` results for the popup tab also doesn't contain `openerTabId`. However, `window.opener` object is not null in the popup window.

From https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab

> The ID of the tab that opened this tab, if any. This property is only present if the opener tab still exists.

In my case, the `opener` tab exists. Sounds like a bug?

Comment: Yeah sounds like a bug. In case the htmls are your own extension files you can try using the proper extension API chrome.windows.create instead of window.open and maybe it'll have the opener id.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not the exact solution but I found out that `chrome.webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget` event passes `sourceTabId` property which is the `openerTabId`. However, this requires `webNavigation` permission.